# Assembly MIPS: checking if a number is positive or not using Shift

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, mips, bit-shift

I browsed some threads aroung here about checking if a number is negative or positive using loops with divisions with 2 and checks with the remainder, but I though that this could happen without any loop at all, using only the shift right logical instruction.

I found [here](https://ske11.readthedocs.io/comparch/03-lecture/) that MIPS is using the two's complement as number represantation, so the MSB (and the others that follow) is 0 for a positive number, opposed to a negative which is 1.

But how can this be functional in MIPS?

My poor code tries got so confusing and mind-numbing that I deleted everything I've written and went back to the start of all.

Are there any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear, what you want to achieve, what should be result? Some example with input values and output values, or output action description would help. If you just want to test whether number is negative (without content modification), then there's branch instruction doing that: `bltz` (branch less than zero). If you want to calculate sign value (-1, 0, 1), that's more tricky, I would branch on zero to return it, then `sra` by 31 bits (result will be -1 or 0 by sign of input), then `or 1` to get +1 for positive numbers and return it.

Comment: Try looking at compiler output for a C function that does what you want.  It sounds like you don't understand signed integers in binary at all, and maybe seeing how a compiler does it will help you understand https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement.  (Nearly every modern CPU architecture uses 2's complement integers.)